# Add required class to an input field if radio box is checked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add required class to an input field dynamically.
If `yes` radio button is checked means `required` field should be added to an input field.
If `no` radio button is checked means `disabled` property should be added to that input field.
What I did wrong??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.disabilityRadioBtn').load(function() {
    if ($('.disabilityRadioBtn input[name="disability"]:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
      $('#txtDisDet').addClass('required');
    } else {
      $('#txtDisDet').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});

function send() {
  var ack = true;
  $('.required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val == "") {
      alert("enter values");
      ack = false;
    }
  })
  if (ack) {
    alert("sent successfully");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label>name</label>
  <input type="text" class="required">
</section>

<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Disability</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"> <label class="disabilityRadioBtn "><input  class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisYes" value="true">Yes<input class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisNo" value="false"> No</label></label>
</section>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">If Yes,Details</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"><input  class="form-control" type="text" id="txtDisDet" placeholder="Disability Details"></label>
</section>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">send
 </button>
```

Comment: There is a typo! you are missing () at line 3 in send function!

Comment: where is the class "disabilityCheckBox" in your html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the working code for you. There were few missing parts to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=disability]').click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'true') {
      $("#txtDisDet").addClass('required').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $("#txtDisDet").removeClass('required').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  })
});

function send() {
  var ack = true;
  $('.required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      alert("enter values");
      ack = false;
    }
  })
  if (ack) {
    alert("sent successfully");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label>name</label>
  <input type="text" class="required">
</section>

<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Disability</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"> <label class="disabilityRadioBtn "><input  class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisYes" value="true">Yes<input class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisNo" value="false"> No</label></label>
</section>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">If Yes,Details</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"><input  class="form-control" type="text" id="txtDisDet" placeholder="Disability Details"></label>
</section>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">send
 </button>
```

Comment: Have you changed anything in my body content?

Comment: its working only once..do I need to refresh page for each and every time?

Comment: No. I just played with above code and it worked fine even after multiple submits. Can you explain your steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: yes am trying to update one form.. default position of radio button based o json..but it doesn't matter..when i click edit button i can change the `yes` or `no` buttons..Now `yes` button is in checked position when i click `edit` button ,i am changing the radio button to `no`..disablity property added successfully and required class removed successfully..then i can able to add required class and remove disabilty for only first click of yes .

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code and added a small comment to help you understand better.

Short story about what i did bellow:

1. You need to update things on 'change' event, not on 'load'. Basically when value changes, you do something, not when the checkbox is first rendered by browser.
2. The second thing I did is to give an initial value to your checkbox. This is a minor optimization as you avoid writing extra javascript for that case.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Update things when value change, not on load
  $('input[name="disability"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
      $('#txtDisDet').addClass('required');
      $('#txtDisDet').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#txtDisDet').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  })
});

function send() {
  var ack = true;
  $('.required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val == "") {
      alert("enter values");
      ack = false;
    }
  })
  if (ack) {
    alert("sent successfully");
  }
}
```

```css
.required{
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label>name</label>
  <input type="text" class="required">
</section>

<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Disability</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"> <label class="disabilityRadioBtn "><input  class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisYes" value="true">Yes<input class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisNo" value="false" checked>No</label></label>
</section>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">If Yes,Details</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"><input  class="form-control" type="text" id="txtDisDet" placeholder="Disability Details" disabled></label>
</section>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">send
 </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so much things to consider.

1. You are executing the event when you are loading the HTML element (at least you try). In this way use `ready` instead of `load`.
2. What i think you need is to add an event on the radio change.

Overall here is a snippet whit debug to give u a look when those events execute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //change event
  $('.disabilityRadioBtn input[name="disability"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
      console.log('changed to yes');
      $('#txtDisDet').addClass('required');
      $('#txtDisDet').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      console.log('changed to no');
      $('#txtDisDet').removeClass('required');
      $('#txtDisDet').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
  
  //ready event
  $('.disabilityRadioBtn').ready(function() {
    console.log('loaded but no value was selcted');
    if ($('.disabilityRadioBtn input[name="disability"]:checked').val() == 'true') {
      $('#txtDisDet').addClass('required');
      $('#txtDisDet').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#txtDisDet').removeClass('required');
      $('#txtDisDet').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});

function send() {
  var ack = true;
  $('.required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val == "") {
      alert("enter values");
      ack = false;
    }
  })
  if (ack) {
    alert("sent successfully");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label>name</label>
  <input type="text" class="required">
</section>

<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">Disability</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"> <label class="disabilityRadioBtn "><input  class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisYes" value="true">Yes<input class="required" type="radio" name="disability" id="chkDisNo" value="false"> No</label></label>
</section>
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <label class="col-xs-12">If Yes,Details</label>
  <label class="col-xs-12"><input  class="form-control" type="text" id="txtDisDet" placeholder="Disability Details"></label>
</section>
<button id="send" onclick="send()">send
 </button>
```